# Image from WebView dragged onto IKImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, ikimageview

I have **WebView** where I load content of webarchive. In the same view I have **IKImageView** outlet. Image drag n drop from web view onto image view doesn't work for me.

What is weird, it works when I drag photo e.g. from iPhoto onto the same image view.
Also, I can drag image from my web view onto **NSScrollView** (which creates a link to the image) and I can drag the same photo onto a new Mail message (created an image as expected).

IKImageView has "Supports Drag and Drop" enabled in the IB.

What am I missing here?

Comment: “Image drag n drop from web view onto image view doesn't work for me.” Please be more specific. What happens instead?

Comment: I can drag an image (which turns to thumbnail and is shadowed out) but hovering over IKImageView does not switch cursor to the one with green plus sign and releasing the mouse button causes my dragged image to "go back" to the web view (to the original image place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the best way to handle d'n'd in my case is via `WebArchivePboardType`.
Then:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard *pboard;
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask;

    sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    // Create image data from webarchive stored in a pasteboard.    
    NSData *image = [pboard dataForType:WebArchivePboardType];
    WebArchive *webArchive = [[WebArchive alloc] initWithData:image];

    // Let's see what are we dragging.
    for (WebResource *subresource in [webArchive subresources])
    {
        NSString *mimeType = [subresource MIMEType];
        if ([mimeType hasPrefix:expectedMimeTypeStartsWith])
        {
            NSData *data = [subresource data];

            CFDataRef imgData = (CFDataRef)data;
            CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);

            CGImageRef image;

            if ([mimeType hasSuffix:@"png"])
            {
                image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);   
            }
            else if ([mimeType hasSuffix:@"jpeg"])
            {
                image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
            }

            [self setImage:image imageProperties:nil];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IKImageView` is probably expecting a pasteboard of `NSFilenamesPboardType`, how does the webview handle dragging images?